# Loop over Array of Components and render them?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Seems like an interesting programming problem.

Suppose you make some `styled-components` like this:

```js
const foo = styled.div`
   font-size: 1rem
`
const bar = styled.div`
   font-size: 2rem
`
```

Then create an `array` of them:

```js
const styledArr = [ foo, bar ];
```

## How would you solve this problem to render components and pass props by using an array loop?

```js
class App extends React.Component<IAppProps> {
   render() {
      return <>
          // This is not a thing?
          {styledArr.map(a => {
              <a {...this.props['a']} />
          }}
      </>
   }
}
```

---

Normally you would do this, which is less efficient:

```js
class App extends React.Component<IAppProps> {
   render() {
      return <>
          <Foo {...this.props.foo} />
          <Bar {...this.props.bar />
      </>
   }
}
```

Comment: What is not a thing? You just need an uppercase name and return from mapping function `.map(Cmp => <Cmp {... } />)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko : facepalm : Thanks that was easy. When it compiles, would it recognize the props ``<Cmp {...this.props.Cmp} />`` belongs to interface property Foo or Bar?

Comment: I guess you could use `this.props[Cmp.name]` but not sure if TS will be happy about it

Comment: @YuryTarabanko ``console.log(this.props[Cmp.name])`` returns undefined. 

``this.props`` works but how would I get current index name of the Component ``Cmp`` to return ``this.props.Foo``

Comment: I see. If you for some reason still want to have this approach you'd need to specify name somehow. For example make it `const styledArr = [ {name: 'foo', Component: foo }, {name: 'bar', Component: bar } ];` and then `styledArr.map(({Component, name}) => <Component {...this.props[name]}/>)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko That worked, explicitly creating object[] with name and component as properties. Since you were first, post it as an answer and I'll mark it as the right one : )

Comment: Alex Wayne has already invested some time into writing his answer. I think you could accept it since it is very close and detailed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *almost* have it. There two things you need to fix:

1. Custom JSX components must start with a capital letter. This tells JSX to render a component, and not raw HTML.
2. The function you pass to `map()` must `return` each rendered component. Your function has no return value since you use `{}` for function body without a return statement.

```
{styledArr.map(Component => {
    return <Component {...this.props['a']} />
})}
```

Or use an arrow function without `{} to return the component implicitly:

```
{styledArr.map(Component => <Component {...this.props['a']} />)}
```

---

Passing different props to different components in that array however is trickier because there's not an easy way to map array index `0` to the props at `this.props.foo`. If you need to do that, I don't think those items should be an array at all, and you should render them one at a time explicitly.

Comment: Thx for explaining it! Would still be awesome if you can pass props like ``this.props[nameof(Component)]`` for ``foo`` and ``bar``